# Apache Server with PHP8 on REDHAT

Tags: php, linux, apache, redhat, php-8

I have a problem into a RedHat Linux Server (version 7.2) with PHP8 installation.

When I try to start apache I have an error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 99 of /opt/APP10/Procparm/PIX/APA_PHP8114/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/APP10/Logiciel/PHP8027/ext/apache/libphp.so into server: /opt/APP10/Logiciel/PHP8027/ext/apache/libphp.so: undefined symbol: zip_dir_add
```

If I try to comment line into httpd.conf

`LoadModule php_module "/opt/APP10/Logiciel/PHP8027/ext/apache/libphp.so"`

Server Works and Apache runs correctly.

How to determine problem for running Apache and PHP8 ?

I precise this server have no access INTERNET it this only use in a local network so if I install package I do this manually.

Comment: notice the low number of followers for your `php-8` tag. You might want to add just plain `php` tag. Good luck.

Comment: I think it was possible to a problem with libzip module ? Do you execute "yum update libzip" for update version with compatible with php-8 ? Because i have two versions of PHP on this redhat server PHP7.2 and PHP8.1 and i want start 2 this versions on one port 80 and other port 81

Comment: are you updating your php version?

Comment: Hi, i try to change PHP version 7.2.2 to PHP version 8.1 manually.
My server is disconnected to internet and i have just a package tar.gzip of new version of PHP but when i try to start apache with new version i have an error message with libzip module

Comment: I have found a solution :
yum remove libzip.x86_64

i download this libraries :
libzip-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm
libzip-devel-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm

And just reinstall lib this :
rpm –ivh libzip*.rpm